# Passing state variables between views Kotlin Jetpack Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to pass state variables between two Composable views and I'm not sure how to do so. I followed the documentation linked below, but I'm running into an error: Type mismatch: inferred type is String but MutableState was expected

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun SignIn(view: View) {
var name = remember {
    mutableStateOf("")
}

Column (
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
){
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(250.dp))

    Text(
        text = "My Mental Health",
        fontSize = 36.sp
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))

    TextInputField(label = "Email", value = name.value, onNameChange = { name = it })

}

@Composable
fun TextInputField(label: String, value: String, onNameChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    Column (
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp)
            .height(125.dp)
    ){
        Text(
            text = label,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(25.dp)
        )

        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(25.dp)
        )

        TextField(value = value, onValueChange = onNameChange)
    }
}
```

This is the documentation I'm referencing: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return `onNameChange`. All you need to do is pass `MutableState<String>`.

To make `TextField` update inserted text, you need to take a new value and update your remember field. In this case `rememberEmail`.

```
@Composable
fun SignIn(view : View) {
    val rememberEmail = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(paddingValues)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(250.dp))

        Text(
            text = "My Mental Health",
            fontSize = 36.sp
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))

        TextInputField(
            label = "Email",
            valueMutableState = rememberEmail,
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun TextInputField(
    label: String,
    valueMutableState: MutableState<String>,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp)
            .height(125.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = label,
            modifier = Modifier.height(25.dp)
        )

        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier.height(25.dp)
        )

        TextField(
            value = valueMutableState.value,
            onValueChange = {
                valueMutableState.value = it
            }
        )
    }
}
```